# Java - Memcache -MultiThreading

Tags: java, multithreading, memcached

I am having code this way in a thread1,

```
public void run() {
        while (continueToProcess.get()) {
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() > nextFlushTime) {
                    try {
                        String json = (ACTIVE.equals(activeTab)) ? bundleS2JsonStreams() : ((ACTIVE1.equals(activeTab)) ? bundleS4JsonStreams()
                                : bundleS1JsonStreams());
                        if (json != null) {
                            MemcachedInterface.set((ACTIVE.equals(activeTab)) ? memcacheS2Key : ((ACTIVE1.equals(activeTab)) ? memcacheS4Key : memcacheS1Key),json);
                        }                       
                    } catch (Throwable e) {
                        logger.error("Error flushing to memcached, cust: " + customerId, e);
                    }
                    lastBundleTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    nextFlushTime = lastBundleTime + flushInterval;
                }               
        }
        tempThread.setRun(false);
        try {
            tempThread.interrupt();
        } catch (Exception e) {     
        }
    }
```

1) What is need of MemcachedInterface here to put the json data with keys like memcacheS1Key? I mean why MemcachedInterface is used here?

2) Then second thread tempThread is invoked from first thread1... and its run method is set to false...

```
tempThread.setRun(false);
```

what is acatullay does?

3) And if we call `tempThread.interrupt();`

on second thread will it's execution will be stopped and again will be started only if this thread1 is started again?

Comment: `Thread#setRun` does not exist - what is `tempThread`?

Comment: Here tempThread is the second thread and this setrun is an  AtomicBoolean  variable.AtomicBoolean run = new AtomicBoolean(true);

Comment: you need to add more data. the entire code will be helpful. and also the context. do you know what memcache is and what it does ?